# What is the best way to display text, images and 2d wpf animation content?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

What is the best way to display text, images and 2d wpf animation content in WPF? I am developing a desktop application which is supposed to display such content in an organized and easily navigable way But i don't know how to display the content. 
I have considered using Flow document for the text and image but it doesn't provide facilities for wpf animations. I can separate the text image part from the wpf animation but that might make management of resources harder. What is the proper way displaying such content?


**PS** I am using Expression Blend to design the user interface and to animate some resources and The application is an **electronic magazine**

Comment: Totally depends on what you are going to be doing; a 2D scroller game? Web browser? Graphic design? Text editor?

Comment: @DourHighArch, It is an interactive e-magazine

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this but FlowDocument has animation

[FlowDocument.BeginAnimation Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.beginanimation.aspx)